# How can I call this method? Arrays.deepToString(method.solution())

Tags: java

I'm trying to call the method in my main class. I keep getting the error code on this:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(method.solution(arr1, arr2, signs)));
```

This is the error message:

```
symbol:   method solution(int[][],int[][],boolean[][])
location: variable method of type Test
```

Here's the result I should see :

```
[[10,8,-7],[-9,8,-11]]
```

Here's my code :

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    class Solution {
        public int[][] solution(int[][] arr1, int[][] arr2, boolean[][] signs) {
            int[][] answer = {{}};
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
                if(signs[i][i] == true){
                    sum += arr1[i][i];
                } else{
                    sum -= arr2[i][i];
                }
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test method = new Test();
        int[][] arr1 = {{5,7,1},{2,3,5}};
        int[][] arr2 = {{5,1,6},{7,5,6}};
        boolean[][] signs={{true,true,false},{false,true,false}};
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(method.solution(arr1, arr2, signs)));
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the sum of the arrays. If the sign is true, the number is positive. If the sign is false, the number is negative.
Here's an example:

```
arr1 = [[1],[2]], arr2 = [[3],[4]], sign = [[true],[false]],
result = [[4],[-6]]
```

Comment: You are mixing up nested class and have no reason to do so. Put Class solution in its own class. Create an Object of Solution and then invoke a method.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining class Solution inside of class Test, you are then calling solution on the instance of Test, not the instance of Solution, I see no point of having a nested class so I would just remove it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public int[][] solution(int[][] arr1, int[][] arr2, boolean[][] signs) {
        int[][] answer = {{}};
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
            if(signs[i][i] == true){
                sum += arr1[i][i];
            }else{
                sum -= arr2[i][i];
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

It also appears that class Solution line added an extra open curly brace which would also throw an error.

Comment: Thank your for your feedback! Problem solved. However, I need to fix my code to get the right result.